# How to enhance match objectives in Fifa 23 career matches

Tags: fifa-23

I play Fifa 23 on a PC with an Xbox controller and intend to achieve the enhanced objectives when a career match begins.

I can see the objectives screen and it says I should press **L + Hold L**.

[image]

How can I do those with the left stick at the same time? If I press it down and press the left stick to the right, it does nothing but switches to the next objective.

Do you have any hint how I should set those objectives?

Comment: I feel like when it says < L > it means use the left analog stick to move between the objectives, and then hold "L" the keyboard letter to enhance it.  But it would be weird for the game to mix inputs like this...

Comment: @TimmyJim Unfortunately no, 'L' doesn't indicate the L on the keyboard. It's some strange combination of the controller buttons and sticks. Maybe noone has ever tried to enhance the objectives and went for the minimum... :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is just a very unlucky phrasing that makes us confused. It says that *in general* you can "*select AN objective to enhance*" it.

It should be clear that it is precisely **ONE (1) objective** that can be enhanced (an not an objective in general in all cases).

It should be phrased like "*select this as THE enhanced objective*".

Answer (score 0):

Use left stick to navigate through the three objectives and wait(or press and hold "A" to skip altogether), that should do it.

Comment: If I skip with the A button, then none of the objectives are enhanced. It's just so strange that this setting is so confusing in a 20+ years old game series... I think, I have to ask in the official forum, it seems like a really advanced setting.